# How can I edit an object which is the child of another object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I am quite new to ASP.NET so I am probably struggling with this more than I should be. I have two custom classes, defined as follows:

```
public class Job
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Address Pickup { get; set; }
    public Address Dropoff { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

I am having them displayed on the Job's index page by getting all the jobs and returning them as a list, then in the `Index.cshtml` I am able to extract some fields for the addresses to return something meaningful:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcJobs.Models.Job>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pickup) Address
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Dropoff) Address
            </th> 
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <pre>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pickup.AddressLine1)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pickup.AddressLine2)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pickup.AddressLine3)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pickup.City)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pickup.Postcode)</pre>

            </td>
            <td>
                <pre>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dropoff.AddressLine1)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dropoff.AddressLine2)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dropoff.AddressLine3)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dropoff.City)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dropoff.Postcode)</pre>
                <a asp-action="Addresses/Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Dropoff.ID">Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This displays each job in a table with their addresses properly formatted and displayed. It wasn't difficult to figure out the generated `Index.cshtml` file and adjust it accordingly. Unfortunately, the generated `Edit.cshtml` file is very differently formatted:

```
@model MvcJobs.Models.Job
<form asp-action="Edit">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Job</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ID" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Data" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Data" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Data" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

As the data is accessed and returned in a different way, I don't know how to go about displaying the attributes for each address, allowing them to be edited and then saving them. Any advice at all is welcome. Basically, I'd like the form to display not only the Job details but also the details for each address, and when I hit save it updates the job and both addresses associated with it.

Thanks.

Comment: `<input asp-for="Pickup.AddressLine1"... />`

Comment: When I try this it returns a blank textbox and the input does not change the object.

Comment: The above is the equivalent of `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pickup.AddressLine1)`

Comment: I've been looking into it and I think that for some reason my Address objects are not properly linking to the Job objects, at least not persistently. When refreshing the index, the display shows no addresses associated with any jobs, so something else must be broken, probably when I'm assigning the Job's Pickup and Dropoff addresses. I'll feedback when I know more. Thanks.

Comment: So it's probably nothing to do with the form. Reloading the page after generating the objects seems to cause some issue with the binding. The database I'm pulling from has DropoffID and PickupID columns in the Job table, and these do seem to sync up with the IDs of the appropriate Addresses, but when the Job objects are loaded in the controller the Pickup and Dropoff are null. I have no idea why there is this disconnect, but it looks like the Job just isn't finding the Address objects. Do I need to assign them every time they are required in the controller? I may have to make another question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (and in direct relation to my question) why would the application generate two wildly different display formats for the Index, Delete and Details views compared with the Create and Edit pages? (The latter displaying with ```@Html.DisplayFor()``` and the former with ```asp-for=""```) I understand that one is focused towards displaying data rather than accepting input, but why would the views not follow a standard convention?

Comment: `<input asp-for="Data" class="form-control" />` is not asp.net-mvc-5 its asp.net-core-mvc (you have not tagged the question correctly). core-mvc uses tag helpers in preference to `HtmlHelper` methods in templates, but there is no equivalent tag helper for `DisplayFor()` (it just generates text, not html)